# Laravel MVC (PHP), Request error messages

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request, message

I'm developing a page on my system to change the users password, and the validation is working fine, but i got no error messages.

(I'm not showing the USES/imports, but it is fine)

Here's my Request:

```
class SenhaRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'senha_antiga' => 'required|min:6|max:24',
            'nova_senha' => 'required|min:6|max:24|same:nova_senha_r',
            'nova_senha_r' => 'required|min:6|max:24|same:nova_senha'
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            'same' => 'A :attribute e a :other devem ser iguais.',
            'required' => 'O campo :attribute é obrigatório!',
        ];
    }
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
class MudarSenhaController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return view('account/senha');
    }

    public function update(SenhaRequest $request) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('nova_senha'));

        $user->save();

        return redirect()->action('Account\AccountController@index');
    }
}
```

And on my view i have:

```
@if(!empty($errors->all()))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all as $error)
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

The div with alert appears when some of the validation fails, but i got no messages. I'm new to laravel and OO php, sorry about anything.

Comment: `$errors->all()` not `$errors->all` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code (as @Jeemusu said) should be like this:

([Laravel 5.3 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors))

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

([Laravel 5.4 and 5.5 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors))

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```